# python 2.7, xml, beautifulsoup4: only return matching parent tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse some XML, but am running into issues with forcing it to only select the request tag if it's a parent tag. For example, part of my XML is:

```
<Messages>
    <Message ChainCode="LI" HotelCode="5501" ConfirmationID="5501">
      <MessageContent>
        <OTA_HotelResNotifRQ TimeStamp="2014-01-24T21:02:43.9318703Z" Version="4" ResStatus="Book">
          <HotelReservations>
            <HotelReservation>
              <RoomStays>
                <RoomStay MarketCode="CC" SourceOfBusiness="CRS">
                  <RoomRates>
                    <RoomRate EffectiveDate="2014-02-04" ExpireDate="2014-02-06" RoomTypeCode="12112" NumberOfUnits="1" RatePlanCode="RAC">
                      <Rates>
                        <Rate EffectiveDate="2014-02-04" ExpireDate="2014-02-06" RateTimeUnit="Day" UnitMultiplier="3">
                          <Base AmountBeforeTax="749.25" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                          <Total AmountBeforeTax="749.25" CurrencyCode="USD" />
                        </Rate>
                      </Rates>
                    </RoomRate>
                  </RoomRates>
                  <Total AmountBeforeTax="2247.75" CurrencyCode="USD">
                    <Taxes Amount="0.00" />
                  </Total>
                </RoomStay>
              </RoomStays>
            </HotelReservation>
          </HotelReservations>
        </OTA_HotelResNotifRQ>
      </MessageContent>
    </Message>
  </Messages>
```

I've gotten the whole thing parsed how I need it with the exception of the "Total" tag.

The total tag I'm trying to get is:

```
 <Total AmountBeforeTax="2247.75" CurrencyCode="USD">
     <Taxes Amount="0.00" />
 </Total>
```

What's happening, is it's returning the "Total" tag that is a child of RoomRates\RoomRate\Rates\Rate. I'm trying to figure out how to specify it to just return the RoomStays\RoomStay\Total tag. What I currently have is:

```
soup = bs(response, "xml")

messages = soup.find_all('Message')

for message in messages:
    hotel_code = message.get('HotelCode')

    reservations = message.find_all('HotelReservation')
    for reservation in reservations:
        uniqueid_id = reservation.UniqueID.get('ID')
        uniqueid_idcontext = reservation.UniqueID.get('ID_Context')

        roomstays = reservation.find_all('RoomStay')
        for roomstay in roomstays:

            total = roomstay.Total
```

Any ideas on how to specify the exact tag I'm trying to pull? If anyone is wondering about the for loops, it's because normally there are multiple "Message", "Hotel Reservation", "Room Stay", etc tags, but i've removed them to only show one. There can also sometimes be multiple Rate\Rates tags, so I can't just ask it to give me the 2nd "Total" tag.

Hopefully I've explained this okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There can also sometimes be multiple Rate\Rates tags, so I can't just ask it to give me the 2nd "Total" tag.

Why not just iterate over all the `Total` tags and skip the ones that have no `Taxes` child?

```
reservations = message.find_all('HotelReservation')
for reservation in reservations:
    totals = reservation.find_all('Total')
    for total in totals:
        if total.find('Taxes'):
             # do stuff
        else:
             # these aren't the totals you're looking for
```

If you more generally want to eliminate those that have no child nodes, you could do either of these:

```
if next(total.children, None):
    # it's a parent of something

if total.contents:
    # it's a parent of something
```

Or you could [use a function instead of a string as your filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
total = reservation.find(lambda node: node.name == 'Total' and node.contents)
```

Or you could look at other ways to locate this tag: it's a direct child of `RoomStay` rather than just a descendant; it's not a descendant of `Rate`; it's the last `Taxes` descendant under a `RoomStay`; etc. All of these can be done just as easily.

---

That being said, this seems like a perfect job for XPath, which `BeautifulSoup` doesn't support, but `ElementTree` and `lxml` do…

Comment: forgot to mention that the "Taxes" child wont always exist, so unfortunately i don't think either solution would work :/ but i will try to look into ElementTree and LXML.

Comment: @crookedleaf: Then what _is_ the rule you want? Whatever it is, you can write—I showed how to write one alternative, and listed three other possible alternatives that would be just as simple. But you have to know which one you want before you can code it.

Comment: @abarnet Actually, didn't notice your second solution had 2 different solutions in it, and the third solution wasn't there when I originally looked. Essentially, I am trying to get the $2247.75 as a variable. What I was originally hoping for was to do something like "total = roomstay.Total.get('AmountBeforeTaxes')" which would give me what I was trying to achieve if it weren't for the previous "Total" tag. I will try the other 2 solutions.

Comment: @crookedleaf: The two versions of the second solution are roughly equivalent, and the third solution is just a different way of writing the second version of the second solution; they'll all finding a `Total` that has at least on child, which is what your title asks for, although I'm not sure it's what you actually want. And again, you _still_ haven't explained what the actual rule you need is. I gave some possible rules that seem like they would work in your example, but I don't know if they would work in your real data. Only you know that.

Comment: I may have gotten my words mixed up a bit, but the subject is as accurate as I could think of. The "Total" tag I need will always be a parent, but it just may not contain "Taxes". It may instead contain "Fee", "Cancellation Fee", "Modification Fee", etc. Your second and third solutions both work perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.